# Porting zepto plugin to jquery

Tags: jquery, reporting-services, zepto

Im using the a framework that relies on jquery. Id like to add the page transition plugin found here: https://github.com/dgileadi/zepto-page-transitions

The plugin is built on zepto and Im trying to port it to run on Jquery 1.9.1, but I cant get it to work. If someone could help me Id be very grateful!

Id thought id be as simple as just replacing Zepto with JQuery but I cant get it to work :)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what errors you are getting and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I wrote Jquery but should be JQuery, got it to work. I ended up writing my own transitions though - it was to much flickering going on  otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change "Zepto" to "jQuery" (that's a small "j") in the file transition.js, that works for me